# Is it required to run the sharepoint product configuration wizard if we install windows security updates

Tags: 2013, administration, patching, configuration-wizard, windows

We have sharepoint enterprise farm 2013, and yesterday our system admin patch the sharepoint application server, where they installed some windows security updates + updates for windows, as follow:-

[image]

so i ave the following questions:-

1. Should we run the sharepoint product configuration wizard? or since the updates do not contain sharepoint/office updates, then it is not required to run the sharepoint product configuration wizard?
2. if the answer to the fist question is that it is not required to run the SP product configuration wizard, then is there any harm of running it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the windows update does not contains the SharePoint updates then no need to run the Configuration wizard.

their is no harm to run it if you want, but keep in mind it will cause an outage on the server where it is running so plan it.

Comment: i provided a screen shot of the updates where all of them are windows updates (security and non-security).. and yes i know that running the SP Configuration wizard will cause the sharepoint services to stop, so i will plan it and inform the users accordingly..thnx,, as i will be more comfortable if i run it, although as you mentioned it is not required in my case..

Comment: if they are not SharePoint then no need to worry. again choice is urs about running or not running. i think flip the coin.